# Postgres column "value" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-constant

I'm building a command that will execute a direct psql query on an operating system (Ubuntu) command line. Strangely enough the following error always occurs: ERROR: column "value" does not exist.

However, the query works if you are directly logged into the database.

Query:

```
psql -U testuser -x -c 'SELECT * FROM table where name = "value"'
```

I have already try different quotes , but it not works
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: use single quotes. Double quotes means a column name.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS

Comment: Hello JGH, i have already tried, but i got exactly the same error message.